# gradle.properties. Unused property

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a gradle.properties file in the project of Android Studio. I put a few lines inside the file_:

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

If I put the mouse over those properties, a mesagge appears saying:

> Unused property. This inspection reports all properties not referenced outside of the properties file.

Someone know how to enable this properties? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. open this in windows C:\Users\user3\ .gradle
2. edit or create a gradle.properties file and open it with text editor
3. copy and paste these there

> org.gradle.daemon=true
>       org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx6144m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>       org.gradle.parallel=true
>       org.gradle.configureondemand=true

4. invalidate cache and restart android studio

Note: change memory values as per your system configuration

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have the gradle.properties in the project folder, not the user folder

Comment: So.. I have the gradle.properties in: C:\Users\myUser\gradle.properties

Comment: Gradle looks for gradle.properties files is these places:
- in project build dir (that is where your build script is)
- in sub-project dir
- in gradle user home (defined by the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable, which if not set defaults to USER_HOME/.gradle)