# Android Studio - Gradle build failing - Java Heap Space

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Android Studio 2.2.3.  I've been building an APK for android with my current project with success until very recently.  As far as I know, nothing was changed except a data file, and my "Build APK" step mysteriously started failing with this message in the gradle console:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':VrSamples:Native:myproject:Projects:Android:packageDebug'.
> Java heap space
```

and in my "messages" window I see this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':VrSamples:Native:myproject:Projects:Android:packageDebug'.
> Java heap space
mple, the following line, in the gradle.properties file, sets the maximum Java heap size to 1,024 MB:
<em>org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m</em>
<a href="http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html">Read Gradle's configuration guide</a><br><a href="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gc-ergonomics.html">Read about Java's heap size</a>
```

I've tried many things:

- Reset version control to previous version I know was generating APK's fine
- Re-clone the entire project in a new location to rule out and intermetiate files that might be pulled in with the .gitignore, to guarantee it's a fresh build
- Rebooted my computer
- re-installed android studio
- Run the clean step, rebuilt, manually deleted intermediate files
- Added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m to my gradle.properties file
- increased the 1024m to 4096m
- manually increased the -Xmx value in both Android Studio\bin\studio.exe.vmoptions and the 64-bit equivalent

I'm puzzled as to why I'm suddenly hitting this issue now, and why I can't seem to be able to re-create the APK's I've been building without problems until recently.  As far as I'm aware, I also haven't updated any libraries either.

Would appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue, tips on how to debug this kind of thing down the road, etc.

Comment: Check out @Faiz Siddiqui 's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045417/android-studio-gradle-could-not-reserve-enough-space-for-object-heap

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I noticed that when I open the gradle.properties folder in my Android Studios project, and hovered over any line, it gave a warning about "unused property".  That put me on the path to do another google search for "Android Studio gradle.properties unused property" and I found this:

[gradle.properties. Unused property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790955/gradle-properties-unused-property/39791066#39791066)

and this:

[JVM arguments gradle cannot be set in gradle.properties file for Android Studio 2.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531536/jvm-arguments-gradle-cannot-be-set-in-gradle-properties-file-for-android-studio)

The issue is that, at least for me, Windows+Android Studio seems to ignore the gradle.properties file in my project.  You need to create one here:
`C:\Users\<username>\.gradle\gradle.properties`

Then, as suggested in other threads such as the one linked to by @Kevin Tan above, I was able to increase the memory by adding a line such as this:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m
```

Now I no longer hit the issue

Comment: When I try this option, I get the error:   

Expiring Daemon because JVM heap space is exhausted
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build after running out of JVM memory

Comment: what does the XX: mean?

Answer (score 20):

Use this in gradle.properties

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12800M
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works for me. 
Before was Xmx6072M and I got this error.

Comment: are you setting the heap size to 12 gigs?  That doesn't seem like it should be necessary.

Answer (score 7):

By default, Android Studio has a maximum heap size of 1280MB. If you are working on a large project, or your system has a lot of RAM, you can improve performance by increasing the maximum heap size for Android Studio processes, such as the core IDE, Gradle daemon, and Kotlin daemon.

If you use a 64-bit system that has at least 5 GB of RAM, you can also adjust the heap sizes for your project manually. To do so, follow these steps:

Click File > Settings from the menu bar (or Android Studio > Preferences on macOS).
Click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings.

For more Info click

[https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Deq.png)

[image]

Comment: So basically the gradle.properties heap configurations are useless unless you run gradle from outside the studio

Comment: Be sure to invalidate caches and restart