# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug' - Java heap space

Tags: android, sqlite, build, package, android-studio-2.3

I am getting this error in Android Studio logs when I am trying to build an APK.

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
Java heap space**

This issue is coming when I am trying to build an APK with 350 MB size of .sqlite in assets directory. When I removed the .sqlite file then issue is gone.

My studio64.exe.vmoptions file for studio:

```
-Xms2048m
-Xmx3840m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=960m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=250
-da
-Djna.nosys=true
-Djna.boot.library.path=

-Djna.debug_load=true
-Djna.debug_load.jna=true
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Didea.paths.selector=AndroidStudio2.3
-Didea.platform.prefix=AndroidStudio
-Didea.jre.check=true
```

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this? I have a huge mp4 file and keep getting this error too. I have also found this stackoverflow question here, perhaps it can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645747/android-studio-gradle-build-failing-java-heap-space/41685614

Comment: It doesn't help me as I already tried with @fluffyBatman answer.

Answer (score 29):

Add this at the end of `gradle.properties` file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=512m -Xmx512m
```

Comment: Where i can find gradle.properties

Comment: Go to your project directory. It's in the root directory.

Comment: In my code, there is no gradle.properties file. Need to create it myself?

Comment: If there is none already, then, yeah, go ahead and create one. Take a look here for help http://stackoverflow.com/a/37389861

Comment: I have added gradle.properties as you said but no success. I attached screen shot of error, gradle.properties code and the .sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

clean the project and try again

On root folder

cd android

./gradlew clean

cd ..

react-native run-android