# Exception in app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForRelease

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I recently updated my gradle version to `gradle-5.2.1`
but during creating release apk I am getting exception is there any way to solve this ?

```
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 28
studio verion is 3.4.1
SDK version 26.1.1
```

---

```
dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
}
```

It took 17min trying to build 
after that studio gave exception

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForAmazonRelease'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:117)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:184)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveIncrementalChangesTaskExecuter.java:84)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:74)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:94)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.tree.MethodNode.visitJumpInsn(MethodNode.java:425)
at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2043)
at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1275)
at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:679)
at com.android.tools.r8.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:391)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.parseCode(JarCode.java:323)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.triggerDelayedParsingIfNeccessary(JarCode.java:293)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.JarCode.registerCodeReferences(JarCode.java:220)
at com.android.tools.r8.graph.DexEncodedMethod.registerCodeReferences(DexEncodedMethod.java:766)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.processNewlyLiveMethod(Enqueuer.java:1647)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.trace(Enqueuer.java:1489)
at com.android.tools.r8.shaking.Enqueuer.traceApplication(Enqueuer.java:1450)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:322)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:251)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.lambda$runForTesting$1(R8.java:242)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8$$Lambda$630/1947509183.run(Unknown Source)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:62)
at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withR8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:50)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.runForTesting(R8.java:238)
at com.android.tools.r8.R8.run(R8.java:148)
at com.android.builder.dexing.R8Tool.runR8(r8Tool.kt:189)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.R8Transform.transform(R8Transform.kt:260)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
```

my gradle-wrapper.properties file contain

```
    distributionPath=wrapper/dists
    zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
    zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
    android.enableR8=false
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.2.1-all.zip
```

Comment: You can disable `R8` in `gradle.properties` `android.enableR8=false`.

Comment: @NickBapu already did

Comment: To solve this, go to File->"Invalidate Caches / Restart..." and clean your caches and restart Android Studio. Wait to rebuild gradle is finished. After go to Build->Clean Project and finally go to Build->Rebuild Project. It could be issue with the amazon lib you are integrating, if possible can you share the details on amazon lib you are trying to integrate.

Comment: @RanjanKumar i did this too ,and restart machine also nothing happened

Comment: check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645747/android-studio-gradle-build-failing-java-heap-space/58266674#58266674

Comment: In your logs I see this, Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space. Maybe you just need to increase heap size?